# ReactJS simulating events from different context

Tags: reactjs

I am aware of React Test Utils that can be used to simulate events when testing, however I have a browser extension that doesn't have access to the context of the page. I would like to be able to interact with the DOM (click events and filling out fields), however it seems that the state is not updated by a page running with ReactJS. Is there a way to this at all?

Comment: Can you put an example online with jsfiddle or something? As far as I know, the DOM events trigger the React events. Like the following triggers the React onClick handler of the corresponding component: `$('#rendered-with-react').click()`

Comment: Can't do a jsfiddle for this, but the example can be illustrated with instagram's login page. [https://instagram.com/accounts/login/](https://instagram.com/accounts/login/) In the console, you can try something like `$("input[name=username]").val("123456")` which will fill the field, but upon manually typing the password you can see the field gets cleared out. After looking deeper into it I discovered the state wasn't being updated.

Comment: I think you need to trigger the corresponding DOM handler instead of only setting the value. Figure out if it needs `onChange` `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp` and fire it after `val()`.

Comment: it must be some event, however `onChange` `onKeyDown` `onKeyUp` `onKeyPress` `onClick` and a few others I tried didn't work. As far as I can tell from the debugger the event that it should respond to is `onKeyDown`.